# change css class properties in extjs

Tags: css, extjs3

I wanted to change the styles of calendar panel using extjs.I am using extjs calendarpanel and datepicker in my EHR application like following link

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/calendar/index.html

when selecting a date from datepicker if the day is a public holiday,(that is get from database on select event )i want to change  the background color of calendarpanel  to gray color.Is it possible?is any way to change the css class properties using extjs3.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a custom class to the cell you need, for example here is how it works with the 15. day of month:

```
Ext.get(Ext.get('mydatepicker').query('td.x-datepicker-active[title*="15,"]')[0].id).addCls("mynewclass")
```

You can take a look to that [Extjs 2/3 plugin](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=148587)

Comment: the code selects the td with title "15" from your calendar picker and add a css class "mynewclass" to it. You have to declare the css for it

Answer (score 1):

you can override the extjs css with the using cls property for the particular element.Here is 
i am using own css class for the text.

```
{ 
 text:'Create App',
cls:'app42CreateApp',
 },
```